# VSCode open specific file on startup

Tags: visual-studio-code, startup, restart

Is it currently possible to set a specific file to open on startup in VSCode? 
I have the 'To Do Tasks' extension installed and I want to open my TODO file by default each time I load VSCode.

Using Version 1.12.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Edit: I think the best way is to use extensions that can run commands on startup. Example is: [Auto Run Command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gabrielgrinberg.auto-run-command)

---

You can either create some shortcut for command `code "path/to/file.todo"` or
change link's options.

For example(windows):

link => properties => shortcut => target => `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "D:/howto.todo"`

[VSCode CLI documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line)

---

Another way is to [Pin editors](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_46#_pin-tabs). With setting `"workbench.editor.pinnedTabSizing": "compact",` they take very little space.

Comment: Nice...I didn't even think about this method. Thanks!

Comment: Please explain how to do the link thing. The docs don't seem to include anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution:

Use an auto-run task:

1. Allow automatic tasks with this command: `Tasks: Manage Automatic Tasks in Folder`.
2. Set up a task in the folder:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Auto-open my-todo file.",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "code my-todo.md",
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "folderOpen",
            },
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "silent",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": false,
                "clear": false,
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The key is to set `runOptions / runOn` to "folderOpen".

More details here: [How to run a command automatically in VS Code when you open a project](https://www.roboleary.net/vscode/2020/10/19/vscode-task-onstartup.html)