# Open default file when opening a workspace in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to get VS Code to open a specific file when opening a workspace? I always want to see my "to do" file when I open a workspace.

Comment: Similar to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851364/vscode-open-specific-file-on-startup)